# Facebook login with ionic4 fails

Tags: android, typescript, facebook, ionic-framework, ionic4

I've added facebook login to my ionic 4 application.
It is working good on some devices, but most of the devices are not working.

what happens that it just load when the user clicks the button then back again to the same page. without opening Facebook to authorize or any other response.

Here is my code:

```js
  facebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
    return this.facebook.login(['email'])
    .then( response => {
      const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
        .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);

      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
        .then( success => { 
          console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success)); 
          this.isLogged = true;
          // tslint:disable-next-line: no-unused-expression
          this.router.navigate(['']);
          console.log('logged in');
        });

    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that something flashes very fast as it opens facebook authorizing dialogue but closes it right away without waiting for the user to accept or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that what causes the problem is not setting my facebook app to live, it was in the development mode !!